# How to authenticate a user in Parse iOS SDK using OAuth?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

Parse Server offers OAuth authentication. How can I use the Parse Server's predefined OAuth modules, e.g. Facebook, to sign up a new user or login an existing user of the '_User' class?

The Parse Server [docs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/OAuth) give examples on how to configure the OAuth modules. But how do I use it in an iOS project to login or signup a user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1, create a class extends from both NSObject and PFUserAuthenticationDelegate.

```
class AuthDelegate:NSObject, PFUserAuthenticationDelegate {
    func restoreAuthenticationWithAuthData(authData: [String : String]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

2, register this authentication delegate

```
// parmeter 'forAuthType' is the name of file defined in 
// https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Adapters/Auth/index.js
// such as: google, github, linkedin ......
PFUser.registerAuthenticationDelegate(AuthDelegate(), forAuthType: "google")
```

3, using PFUser.logInWithAuthTypeInBackground method to store user info to _User

```
// for google oauth, authData format will be
// ["id":"PUT_USER_ID_HERE","accesstoken":"PUT_TOKEN_HERE"]
PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: "google", authData:[.....])
```

4, you will see a record is created in _User, with only objectId and authData

Comment: I couldn't find any useful information regarding third party login with parse. I wonder whether i can integrate with Spotify login as well?

Comment: @KesongXie you can see the supported providers here https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/tree/master/src/Adapters/Auth

Comment: How could I get a callback for when the logInWithAuthType function finishes? I read [here](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFUser.html#/c:objc(cs)PFUser(cm)logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:authData:) that it returns "A BFTask that is resolved to @YES if linking succeeds." But what does that mean? How can I use that?

Comment: Nvm, I found an example [here](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC#the-continuewithblock-method)

Comment: @Jacolack If you are still looking for then check this this sample code that shows how it is handled. https://github.com/back4app/SignInWithApple/blob/master/Swift/app/ViewController.swift