# Integrating LinkedIn login in a safe way on parse-server / iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, linkedin-api, parse-server, secret-key

I am running parse-server and want to integrate a LinkedIn login.
If I understand the process correctly the steps are:

1. use the [LinkedIn SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk) or a library like [LinkedinSwift](https://github.com/tonyli508/LinkedinSwift) to get the access_token
2. use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255006/how-to-authenticate-a-user-in-parse-ios-sdk-using-oauth/37688477#37688477) after you get the access token to login with the Parse SDK

However, using the SDKs from step 1 requires to embed the secret key inside your app and LinkedIn themselves state in their [best practices](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/best-practices#keysecret) that you should not do that (for good reason).

I am probably missing something here. Has anyone solved this? To get LinkedIn login working in combination with parse-server and ***NOT*** storing your secret in the app itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should acquire the access token on a server endpoint then send it to your client, then the client can finish the login/linking/signup with option 2.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I take it even a step further by encrypting the token before sending it back to the client. And decrypting it in the linkedin.js OAuth module. This way the token is never exposed and secure.

Comment: Awesome! That would be a nice blog article and we could link it into the docs